# Get sprint capacity through Visual Studio Online Rest API

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

I'm actively using [Visual Studio REST API](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/integrate/api/overview) and I would like to calculate what is the total [capacity](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/get-started/work/work-in-sprints-vs) that each team member has defined for a given sprint.

I've checked the [classification node API](https://www.visualstudio.com/integrate/api/wit/classification-nodes) but the only specific information returned for an iteration is name and start and end date.

Is there any way I could get the total capacity, and ideally also the specific capacity for each team member with their names?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft has updated the VSO REST API and added a resource for capacity:
https://www.visualstudio.com/integrate/api/work/capacity

And another for days off:
https://www.visualstudio.com/integrate/api/work/team-days-off

Answer (score 0):

In theory this is now available. However it doesn't seem to have been officially published yet. Maybe they will feature toggle it soon.

https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/4252627-make-it-possible-to-read-write-the-team-capacity-w

Comment: Yeah, saw that one and even commented there. The URL is pointing nowhere and there is no trace of any capacity resource in the REST API. Quite unfortunate that they announced something and didn't publish it.